# Как в CKEditor запретить изменение форматирования внутри определенного тега?

Tags: ckeditor

Всем привет!
Использую в проекте CKEditor, в окно источника вставляю код из верстки:

```
<a href="#" class="repair_right">   
<div class="relative">
            <img src="img/6-1.jpg" width="614" height="537" alt=""/>
            <div class="repair_right_inner">
                <b class="f17b">Видео в тему</b><br />
                Если прямо сейчас Вы оплакиваете любимую сгоревшую мясорубку, посмотрите этот ролик, надеемся, он поднимет Вам настроение и заставит улыбнуться.
            </div>
        </div>

        </a>
```

Редактор его форматирует таким образом:

```
    <div class="relative"><a class="repair_right" href="#"><img alt="" height="537" src="img/6-1.jpg" width="614" /> </a>
<div class="repair_right_inner"><a class="repair_right" href="#"><b class="f17b">Видео в тему</b><br />
Если прямо сейчас Вы оплакиваете любимую сгоревшую мясорубку, посмотрите этот ролик, надеемся, он поднимет Вам настроение и заставит улыбнуться. </a></div>
<a class="repair_right" href="#"> </a></div>
```

Что нужно сделать, что бы редактор не форматировал блоки внутри тэга а?

Comment: Разделите вопрос и ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решние такое:

```
config.protectedSource.push( /<a[\s\S]*?\>/g ); 
   config.protectedSource.push( /<\/a[\s\S]*?\>/g );
```

То есть разрешаются все тэги внутри